# Who became a professor?

Tags: meaning

In sentence

> They were rescued by Joseph-Louis Liouville, the son of a captain in Napoleon's army who became a professor in the Collège de France.

who became a professor: Joseph or his father?

Photo of the source:
[image]
Why beauty is truth: a history of symmetry / Ian Stewart. ISBN-13: 978-0-465-08236-0

Comment: Joseph-Louis Liouville. Your sentence is missing a comma before "*who*". But I might be wrong. Please include the source of this sentence.

Comment: @Justin in other texts around it sort of ensures that it was Joseph (but not specifically), but can you be sure? Is it a common way in English to mention the same person/thing which was stated in the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: [This article by J J O'Connor and E F Robertson](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Liouville.html) explains the facts. Joseph-Louis, not his father, became a professor. The sentence as given needs a comma after _army_ to have this reading; as it stands, it indicates that it was the father who became a professor:

Comment: << Joseph-Louis Liouville, the son of [a captain in Napoleon's army who became a professor] >> vs the sentence using an incidental parenthetical << Joseph-Louis Liouville, the son of a captain in Napoleon's army, who became a professor = Joseph-Louis Liouville (the son of a captain in Napoleon's army) who became a professor // Depending on the date of the original, the rules surrounding comma usage may have been since tightened on this point.

Comment: @Edwin As it stands, the sentence is _completely_ ambiguous. Without knowing the historical facts, there is absolutely no way to tell who became a professor as the sentence stands. A comma would make it unambiguously the son, but no comma does not make it the father even half-unambiguously. The antecedent of _who_ can just as well be “the son of a captain in Napoleon’s army” as “a captain in Napoleon’s army” – or indeed, going by mere nested proximity, the current sentence might be saying that Napoleon’s army became a professor!

Comment: @Janus I have to agree that it's not definitive without the comma, but I'd say the default reading is the non-parenthetical one, because the comma would as you say clearly disambiguate. And Gricean requirements demand disambiguation (... and so yes, a rewrite would obviously be the best option). But this (in my second main clause) is down to pragmatics and doubtless somewhatOB. // Whichever way you look at it, nowadays this shouldn't get past an editor.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet could you please format it up as an answer so I can accept it? From text ("Why beauty is truth", Ian Steward, ~1995) I couldn't figure out if Joseph's father was a professor in the end or not (it's obvious that Joseph did become a professor eventually in his life). It's pretty satisfactory for me that it's ambiguous though ^^

Comment: @Justin it is so in the source. I appended the image.

Comment: The sentence as printed is ambiguous, but the following sentences strongly imply that the son was the professor.

Comment: Please do not post text as graphics. It discriminates against people with sight deficiencies and it cannot be indexed. Take the trouble to write it out

Comment: @David I was asked to post the source (I guess people didn't believe comma was absent in the source too). The problematic sentence **was** present in the original question (my question was about that specific sentence only, so surrounding sentences may be discarded). And question was mostly about how to read such sentences - not to get an info about whether Joseph's father did become a professor or not ^^

Comment: More pertinent to provide a link or at least a reference. What is the book? And you may be unaware that legal actions are being brought against US websites that are inaccessible to the blind.

Comment: There's almost zero ambiguity, given the facts presented and narrative: given that JLL read through Galois' memoirs AND grasped their importance AND wrote to the French Academy to alert them of their mistake in overlooking them, he seems infinitely more likely to be a professor [and presumably a mathematics professor] than his father. (Unless they were both professors, père et fils, and his father was not necessarily a mathematics professor. But that seems a tortured reading). All this context allows us to guess around the missing comma, in this particular case.

Comment: @smci There is no doubt that Joseph did become a professor at certain age - he was one of the best mathematicians at the time, so it puts some sense into making author telling a reader that his father [maybe] eventually became a professor, thus making his son (Joseph) familiar with math.

Comment: @David It's from the paper book. Should I specify it's caption or ISBN? Or remove photo?

Comment: Give its title author and ISBN. Then it’s probably ok to keep the photo. One has to strike a balance.

Comment: No,  Who became a first baseman.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Poor punctuation leads to poor understanding.  The sentence, as written, is ambiguous.

In context, the math was rescued by the son of an army captain. It's unlikely (but not impossible) that the army captain of the Napoleonic era, would go on to become a professor of mathematics.  Nor would a man's father's credentials likely be of greater significance than his own in this scenario. *So, we can likely conclude this to refer to credentials of the son.*

I'm reminded of the title joke of the book [*Eats, Shoots and Leaves*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eats,_Shoots_%26_Leaves), by Lynne Truss.

> A panda walks into a café. He orders a sandwich, eats it, then draws a gun and proceeds to fire it at the other patrons.
>
> "Why?" asks the confused, surviving waiter amidst the carnage, as the panda makes towards the exit. The panda produces a badly punctuated wildlife manual and tosses it over his shoulder.
>
> "Well, I'm a panda," he says. "Look it up."
>
> The waiter turns to the relevant entry in the manual and, sure enough, finds an explanation. "Panda. Large black-and-white bear-like mammal, native to China. Eats, shoots and leaves."

Comment: I deleted my (Janus') answer. But +1 for your answer. Totally loved the joke!

Comment: @Justin No need to delete. Just click the Community Wiki button when taking someone else's work for an answer. That way you don't earn the rep. Still allows for the answer to be out there.

Comment: Another reason: A professor *would* be likely to rescue the math, a professor's son less so.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously there's a missing comma but **there's almost zero ambiguity, given the specific facts presented and narrative**:

- given that JLL read through Galois' memoirs AND
- grasped their importance AND
- wrote to the French Academy to alert them of their mistake in overlooking them...

JLL seems infinitely more likely to be a professor [and presumably a mathematics professor] than his father. [Unless they were both professors, père et fils, and his father was not necessarily a mathematics professor. But that seems a tortured reading, and in the unlikely event, the article would have said "the professor son of a captain who also became a professor..."]. **All this (both explicit and implicit) context allows us to guess around the missing comma, in this particular case.**

I mean you could argue that it's linguistically also possible that JLL only later in life, became a professor, and in archaeology not anything mathematics-related. But that sounds very unlikely. It's also possible that JLL was a dolphin. **Paraphrasing: all human communication has ambiguities if you scrutinize it hard enough, but we each learn to apply the everyday skill of discarding unlikely and silly hypotheses. This one is no different.**

Comment: The ambiguity is at a grammatical level.  Otherwise, does this differ significantly from my answer above?

Comment: I know **there is initial ambiguity at a grammatical level, exacerbated by the punctuation error; but then that ambiguity is disspelled almost completely by the context**. Your answer doesn't explicitly say that; and it says *"The sentence, as written, is ambiguous."* which we both seem to be agree to be wrong.

Comment: I think the dolphin hypothesis is sufficiently ruled out here, as Napoleon was not known to have any dolphins as captains in his army (and if he had any as captains at all, they would have been in the navy). From biology we can understand that a non-dolphin father's son would also be non-dolphin.  
Other than the last paragraph, this seems like a good answer.

Comment: **Paraphrasing: all human communication has ambiguities if you scrutinize it hard enough, but we each learn to apply the everyday skill of discarding unlikely and silly hypotheses. This one is no different.** My serious point about the article is it doesn't explicitly say JLL was *the* professor, but neither does it explicitly say that JLL wasn't the offspring of a dolphin, via some time-traveler from a future where dolphin reproduction with human traits is very much possible (and if you really want to nitpick, noone proved that JLL was his father's biological son, either).

Answer (score 2):

As requested by OP in comments to post [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/514063/who-became-a-professor#comment1246427_514063) comment as an answer -

> As it stands, the sentence is completely ambiguous. Without knowing
>   the historical facts, there is absolutely no way to tell who became a
>   professor as the sentence stands. A comma would make it unambiguously
>   the son, but no comma does not make it the father even
>   half-unambiguously. The antecedent of who can just as well be “the son
>   of a captain in Napoleon’s army” as “a captain in Napoleon’s army” –
>   or indeed, going by mere nested proximity, the current sentence might
>   be saying that Napoleon’s army became a professor!

Credit - Janus Bahs Jacquet

Comment: Well done. That's the appropriate thing to do.